# c# - visit a link in background

Tags: c#, winforms, http, web, request

How can I "visit" a link in c# without actually displaying the page?
I dont want to post any data, or retrieve any data.
Just make it act like it visited a link.

I do not want to use web browser for this!
But it should function like the .Navigate() in web browser.

I simply want my c# to visit a URL.
This is my code so far and it is not working at all. I even tried setting some data like `?hello=world`, but it did not work either.

```
ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
string postdata = "";
byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postdata);

WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.website.com/page");
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;

Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
stream.Close();
```

I have not been able to find ANYTHING about this on the web. is this even possible?

I want my c# to  visit my desired link. Just "send a visit". I dont know how else to explain it.

It is not a form. It is not getting any data. Nothing like that. Just send a damn "visit" to my site.

Just like `webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.website.com/page");` would do, but I don't use a web browser now.

Comment: in what way hasnt it worked?

Comment: On my website I have a website counter. And I see that it did not increase my website visits. When I manually go to the link, it increments my visits with 1. But when I tried my code, nothing happens. I put this code on a button in my winforms application. It does absolutely nothing. And I dont know why.

Comment: I am fairly sure that "visiting" a link will only retrieve the HTML; it won't run any javascript that your website counter may rely on.

Comment: And why you don't want to use a some `WebBrowser` controls created and used in code?

Comment: It depends a lot on how your counter works.. how is your counter done?

Comment: webBrowser is extremely slow and i just dont like it. i hate internet explorer

Comment: my website counter uses one of those images you embed with some javascript too. and each time someone see that image, it increments the value by one. i just google'd some free website hit counters

Comment: then it wont work - this doesnt run code, it just downloads the html behind the actual page

Comment: It depends on the mechanism which the site is using for counting visitors. If you know which request is important for counting a visit, for example the url of image, you can send the request to that address. But the most simple way which doesn't need discovering how the counter work is browsing using WebBrowser Control. You can simply create them at runtime and use them and dispose them when you finished with them.

Comment: In the case which the site count visitors using requests to the image url, you should know sending a request to the page using WebRequest orWebClient is useless, because they only download the content of page and don't send the request to images or don't run scripts.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Net;

WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadString("http://www.website.com/page");
```

You can't add views to YouTube or other sides like this they whill check if it was a bot or a real click.

Comment: it's not for youtube. it is my own website i am trying to visit.

Comment: then it will work if you want to get the page content just use "string content = client.Downl..."

Comment: if your counter is using JavaScript you cant increase it this way you acually have to run the js-code

Comment: my site has javascript on it. how can i run the js?

Comment: by using a WebBrowser... you also can create a same javascript and greasemonkey to reload you siede all the time

Comment: is there a way to change the internet explorer web browser to google chrome or something? and what happens if the user does not have google chrome installed? would the built-in web browser (with chrome) not work then?

Comment: place this on you webside <script> setTimeout(function() { location.reload(true); }, 1000); </script> navigate to it and it will keep reloading